# Flex canvas with many UIComponents, if one moved are others redrawn/reprocessed?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flexbuilder

I have a canvas called Host with many UIComponents as children, sometimes up to 1000 or 3000 items. This is fine for now, as they are not interactive.

But, I have added a 'marker line' (a 1 pixel wide UI Component with a colored background) to the canvas which follows the mouse movement. **When this UIComponent is added to the Host canvas and moves, everything slow down to a crawl** i.e. takes ages for the UIComponent to move.

What do you think could be causing this? or how to avoid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you move the mouse, you are probably causing the `measure` and `updateDisplayList` methods of every one of those `UIComponent`s to be called. So you may be causing those thousands of components to renegotiate their positions and dimensions with their neighbors.

Without seeing your code I can't get too specific in recommending a solution, but you might try placing a `Canvas` with a transparent background over the canvas that houses the thousands of components, matching its dimensions and location, and use that to move the marker line.

Comment: Overwrote the updateDisplayList function for the canvas, and sure enough, its getting called each time I move the UIComponent, which in turn calles layout functions for all the other components. The transparency canvas gets around this. Good man.

Answer (score 0):

I assume of your 1000 items, only a small portion are on the screen at one time?

If you have that many components, a slow down is expected.  I suggest looking into using a ListBased Class.  Therefore only the items on screen are renderered and you will not have a lot of components hanging out in memory.

Comment: I neeeded to use a canvas to set the x,y for each display object. Think I might be able to prevent offscreen items being rendered by using an 'itemRenderer pool', similar to how the List works.